# Trouble installing 12.04 from cd, blank screen with cursor

Tags: 12.04, installation, asus

I should preface this with saying that this is not my first rodeo. I started playing with Linux in 1999 (Red Hat) and I'm currently typing this on a ThinkPad running 12.04...

When I put in the live cd, I boots, and I can get to the option menu to decide whether to install/run etc, but at any point beyond that I get only a single caret. I can type stuff in, but it goes no where. I've tried the usual stuff like running with nomodeset (thinking it was the intel HD400 graphics, but it is integrated graphics...)

here is the setup:

- ASUS p8z77 pro (with the Atheros AR9485 wifi supposedly, but I'm not that far yet)
- i7 3370k
- 8gig X 2 G.Skill
- Crucial M4 (256 gig)
- LG Super-multi DVD re-writer
- no video card

*UPDATE:*

I though may be it was a bad image on the CD, so I downloaded another iso, and used a USB disk. now it boots to a blank screen. I can see the "press any key to get options" screen, but after that, it just goes to a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*FIXED!*

Turns out my problem was that I had my SSD drive plugged into the wrong port, well the eSata port, which ubuntu shat bricks over.  The only reason I discovered this is because I turned off the splash screen and silent mode.  While my particular issue isn't what will cause all installs to hang, disabling the splash screen and silent mode, will allow you to actually diagnose the issue.

*HOW TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON*

When ubuntu is booting, you should see a dark purple screen with a little man, and a keyboard at the bottom.  Press any key to get to the options menu.

Once at the options menu, press `F6` this will pop up a little menu of common boot options, though none of these are what we want. Press `ESC`.

A line should have appeared that displays a series of boot commands for grub. the last bit will say: `silent showsplash --` remove the `silent` and `showsplash` commands to see exactly what is happening as your live cd (or usb) is booting.  this will show you where the error is, and you can take that to various linux forums/google to actually figure out what is happening.